# typescript es6 import syntax output es5 commonjs module issue

Tags: knockout.js, typescript, commonjs

So the issue I have is that I am trying to use knockout-es5 and output to common js format, but I am writing everything using the es6 syntax.

Now the problem I have is that I do the following:

`import ko from "knockout-es5";`

with the hope that the output when ran through tsc would be:

`var ko = require("knockout-es5");`

However first of all it wont compile because of the `knockout-es5` descriptor file doesnt have a module export, so I went in and added the following to the end of it:

`declare var ko: KnockoutStatic;
export module "knockout-es5" {
  export = ko;
}`

Which then does seem to work, but if you look at the output where it gets used it makes it do `ko.default.yourMethod` rather than `ko.yourMethod` which then doesn't work.

So I am a bit baffled, as I love the ES6 syntax and my code is all written using ES6 imports and exports, but as I am dependent upon non ES6 exported modules I cannot seem to find a workable middle ground, I either remove the knockout default export and no require is included in the output file, or I add the default export and it adds the `default` property.

So is there a way to have my cake and eat it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want

```
import * as ko from "knockout-es5";
```

Your original import is the same as `import {default as ko} from ...`.

Refer to http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html for a comprehensive explanation of the syntax.

Comment: AH! I always thought the `as ko` was a typing not an assignment, thanks for help.